# Clean ink blot on polyamide

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I have a white-ish polyamide coat that got stained with black ink in multiple places (long story short, I helped lift a large carton with 1-day-old stamps on it, both on the carton and on the masking tape that was holding it close, and I touched it with my chest).

The ink is from an anonymous bottle given to me to stamp electoral documents. I have no idea of the brand or composition of the ink. It's not from a ready-made tampon.

The incident happened several days ago but I noticed today.

The coat has a feather down inside, so soaking it completely in a bath might not be the best idea. Also, the coat has a polyester interior (not stained, but if I need to bath the whole thing the bath should not ruin it) and plastic buttons and zippers.

---

I know I need to test everything on some hidden part of the cloth to be sure it works fine.

Comment: Did you consult a professional Dry Cleaning establishment? Can you melt/dissolve a polyamide garment?

Comment: @Stan of course I didn't, I was hoping in some cheap but effective DIY (if there is none, I will just bring it to the cleaner, without even asking him anything but "please, clean this")

Comment: I ruined a white pull-over by trying something, thinking that if it didn't work, I could always bring it to a specialist. What I did was make it permanent. It was pretty expensive for  a "cheap" alternative. Ask first. Maybe the pros will have a suggestion. It isn't in their best interest to mislead you.

Comment: @Stan Oh, I wasn't talking about "if it didn't work" but about "If nobody knows how", but I see your point.

Answer (score 1):

Spot treating with solvent-based cleaners is best. Since you don't know the ink composition, try scrubbing gently (a toothbrush should work for milder solvents, though it might dissolve a bit in stronger ones) on a spot with different solvents, from mild to strongest, to see what works best. *Note that these solvents are poisonous and very flammable!* Use small amounts in a well-ventilated place, away from source of ignition, and with water handy.

From gentle to stronger:

- Alcohols (90% or stronger) (methanol, e.g. [gas-line antifreeze](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0016GXNC4), ethanol or [isopropanol](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LYKTV7Z))
- Diethyl ether (**extremely flammable**), e.g. [engine starting spray](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000LNVWAI)
- Acetone, e.g. [nail-polish remover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B014FPMOZY)
- [Ethyl acetate](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0755JYFJS)
- [Xylene](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XRZW7CK) or toluene, e.g. epoxy thinner ([carcinogenetic](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3053447))

The product links are for reference only; you can probably find the same items locally for less.

Comment: Before you 'scrub' the area with a brush, you might first want to try "blotting" the spots with white cotton balls moistened with the solvent of choice from the above list. Note: Avoid mixing different solvents on the same cotton ball one-after-the-other.

Comment: In the end, mom tried some marseille soap and hot water and it went away.